# /usr/sbin/installer requires root, not Admin, to install a package

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, installation

Prior to Mountain Lion, I was able to install packages with `/usr/sbin/installer` as an Admin user. However, with Mountain Lion, when I try running

```
installer -pkg blah.pkg -target /
```

I get the error

```
installer: Must be run as root to install this package.
```

I've monkeyed with the `IFPkgFlagAuthorizationAction` variable in the package's info.plist, setting it to `AdminAuthorization` and even `UserAuthorization`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I can install with sudo to actually run as `root`, but the software (correctly) expects me to install as a non-`root` users and thus doesn't work.

If I use the GUI Installer.app on the same package (even without modification to `IFPkgFlagAuthorizationAction`), I am prompted for an Admin—not `root`—password and everything works as expected.

How do I get the behavior of the GUI tool from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. ;)

I can't help you run the installer as root while giving the installed files the ownership of a regular user, but you should be able to change the ownership after the install to get the same effect and ultimately get around this restriction.

If, for example, your user account is "myusername" and you have a group such as "_developer" that is a better owners group for the application you are installing, you could reset the ownership after install via something like:

```
sudo chown -R myusername:_developer ~/Library/[MYAPPNAME]
sudo chown -R myusername:_developer ~/Library/Application\ Support/[MYAPPNAME]
```

It seemed to work in my situation. Might help you, too. Of course, paths and user/group names would be particular to your situation. :)